# SSLError in python application, after certificate update

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

As part of updating the SSL/TLS certificate of the web server deployed in the Kubernetes(which the current one will expire soon), I updated the Kubernetes secret (kubernetes.io/tls) with the new crt and key.

After that, the application works fine in the browser.
But, the API calls to the server, (From some python applications running in some pods) are hitting some SSLError.

The same will work if I restore the old certificate for the server.

The error is:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*hostname*',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: *URL*(Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1131)')))

I tried to resolve this by creating the crt and key in different ways from the pfx file.
But the issue remains.

I did some search on - if anything to update in the Kubernetes cluster as part of the certificate change and I couldn't find a solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"host='hostanme'"* Typo?

Comment: @KlausD. I corrected the typo, I masked the actual hostname and url

Comment: What python version is used? And what versions of the packages `requests` and `certifi` are instaled?

Comment: @Robert Python -> 3.8.10, requests->2.25.1, certifi->2021.10.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, the certificate I installed was without the intermediate certificate. The browsers may "fill in the gap" by searching for the missing certificate. Re-install the certificate with the complete chain resolved the issue